# Grab from an Object in a collection in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Traying to grab company ID stored in a user Object in firebase.
[image]

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setError('')
    try {
    const { user } = await signIn(email, password)
    const userID = await user.uid
    const compID = doc(db,  'Users', user.uid)
    console.log(userID + ' USERID')
    console.log(compID.companyID + ' COMPANYID')
    navigate('/Main/Dashboard')
  } catch (e) {
    setError(e.message)
    console.log(e.message)
  }
  }
```

Tried logging it and I get undefined. If I put the whole path in the const compID then I get an invalid error due to having and odd number of selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually fetch the document. What you have done now is create a query but not executing it.

To fetch the user document, do like this instead:

```
const { user } = await signIn(email, password)
const userID = user.uid

const docRef = doc(db, "Users", userID);
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) { // Check if the document exists before accessing data
  const data = docSnap.data()
  // Access compId by:
  const compID = data.companyID
  
  console.log("Here is you company id:", compID);
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

Comment: No worries! Feel free to upvote my answer